# 404 anomaly on one computer only

Tags: url, http-status-code-404

This is weird. On my personal computer at home when I type in my website, I get a 404 error.

No other computer gets the 404 error that I can see from several work computers to relatives, wife's laptop and even my phone using the same WIFI connection.

This only happened after switching my preferred domain under preferred hosting settings from www.xxx.com to xxx.com - perhaps coincidence, perhaps not.

I did this as links in Twitter and Facebook where directing to xxx.com and were giving me 404 errors. Note that the day I made the change the 404 errors went away and I was linking to my website. Then a day later, not working to access my website.

I would suspect nameservers etc but my computer is the only one seemingly exhibiting the problem.

I cleared the browser cache for Chrome and Edge still nothing. I downloaded FireFox and installed fresh and get the same 404 error.

I flushed the dns with ipconfig in administrator mode and it has been over 24 hours since the problem first occurred.

I can get to my website using the IP address fine. I can't using the URL, only on this computer. I even called GoDaddy to make sure it was only my machine and they say they see no problem.

The HOSTS file is virtually empty. and I can use the website with Visual Studio no problem.

Any thoughts? I am stumped on this anomaly.

Comment: Just guesing here, but maybe its a router setting? I know it could be a pain but try doing a factory restore on your router?

Comment: delete windows dns cache?

Comment: Thanks Eric! Using a Verizon JetPack with no router. I would consider the JetPack being blocked but the wife's laptop and my phone also connect using the same JetPack without any problems.

Comment: Odd. Well it sounds like it something with your computer than. Another wild guess, try running a full CCleaner clean. https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again everyone! Your feedback helped me solve the problem. This project was originally started in PHP and moved to from Apache server to ASP.NET. My hosts file still had remnants to xxx.com being local, and not searching outside to the world. Removing 127.0.0.1 xxx.com solved the problem.

THANK YOU!